Column manipulation based on headline values within rows
I have a Pandas dataframe with a column that contains different types of values and I want to create a new column out of it based on the information inside that column. Every few rows there is a kind of "headline" row that should define that values for the following rows until the next headline row that then defines the values for the next rows and so on.
To understand better, here is an example:
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd

data = {'AA': ['', '', '', 'V_525-124', 'gsdgsd', 'hdfjhdf', 'gsdhsdhsd', 'gsdgsd', 'V_535-623', 'hosdfjk', 'hjodfjh', 'hjsdfjo',  'V_563-534', 'hojhdfhjdf', 'hodfjhjdfj', 'hofoj', 'hkdfphdf']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

I want to create a new column BB that would look like that:
import pandas as pd

data = {'AA': ['', '', '', 'V_525-124', 'gsdgsd', 'hdfjhdf', 'gsdhsdhsd', 'gsdgsd', 'V_535-623', 'hosdfjk', 'hjodfjh', 'hjsdfjo',  'V_563-534', 'hojhdfhjdf', 'hodfjhjdfj', 'hofoj', 'hkdfphdf'],
'BB': ['', '', '', 'V_525-124', 'V_525-124', 'V_525-124', 'V_525-124', 'V_525-124', 'V_535-623', 'V_535-623', 'V_535-623', 'V_535-623',  'V_563-534', 'V_563-534', 'V_563-534', 'V_563-534', 'V_563-534']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

The number of rows under each "headline" varies, so the script should sort of check whether the next row is a headline-type, then add the headline value to column BB and then move on down the table until a new headline is detected. I can only think of a for-loop with indices and if-statements but I am sure Pandas offers a more elegant solution.
The "headlines" all start with 'V_' if that helps.

Use where with the condition "column AA starswith V_" -> df['AA'].where(df['AA'].str.startswith('V_')).ffill().fillna('')

You can use where and ffill (forward fill) without the need for loops:

df['AA'].where(df['AA'].str.startswith('V_')).ffill().fillna('')

str.startswith to identify rows where AA column starts with 'V_'.
where to keep identified headline rows in BB column and set other rows to NaN.
ffill to forward fill the last valid headline value down the column until the next headline is identified.
fillna('') to replace remaining NaN values with empty strings



import pandas as pd

data = {'AA': ['', '', '', 'V_525-124', 'gsdgsd', 'hdfjhdf', 'gsdhsdhsd', 'gsdgsd', 'V_535-623', 'hosdfjk', 'hjodfjh', 'hjsdfjo',  'V_563-534', 'hojhdfhjdf', 'hodfjhjdfj', 'hofoj', 'hkdfphdf']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['BB'] = df['AA'].where(df['AA'].str.startswith('V_')).ffill().fillna('')
  
print(df)


You can use Series.str.extract to get all strings that start with V_ or are empty, and then apply df.ffill:
df['BB'] = df['AA'].str.extract('(^V_.*|^$)').ffill()

Output:
            AA         BB
0                        
1                        
2                        
3    V_525-124  V_525-124
4       gsdgsd  V_525-124
5      hdfjhdf  V_525-124
6    gsdhsdhsd  V_525-124
7       gsdgsd  V_525-124
8    V_535-623  V_535-623
9      hosdfjk  V_535-623
10     hjodfjh  V_535-623
11     hjsdfjo  V_535-623
12   V_563-534  V_563-534
13  hojhdfhjdf  V_563-534
14  hodfjhjdfj  V_563-534
15       hofoj  V_563-534
16    hkdfphdf  V_563-534

Regex explained here.

If potential empty strings in the middle need to be ignored, you can use:
df['BB'] = df['AA'].str.extract('(^V_.*)').ffill().fillna('')


df['BB'] = df['AA'].apply(lambda x: x if x.startswith('V_') else None)
df['BB'] = df['BB'].ffill()
print(df)


